# Functions with convex/concave potential

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, convex-analysis

A function $f:A\to A$ has convex/concave potential if there is $F:\mathbb{R}^n\to \mathbb{R}$ such that $\nabla F=f$, and $F$ is convex/concave.

Let $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be a compact set.

Are there efficient ways to generate not trivial examples of such functions such that $f:A\to A$ is onto $A$ ?

Trivial example:
$F=\frac{x^2+y^2}{2}, \nabla F =(x,y)$

Answer (score 1):

Take $$F: \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R} ,$$ defined by $$F(x_1 , ..., x_n ) =\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{j=1}^m x_j^{2n}$$